# How to edit the nativecontacts fields using contact id

Tags: android, native, edit

How to edit firstname,surname,mobilenumber,photo,email,address in native contact in android programmatically using contact id. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?? With this reputation, you should know how to ask.

Comment: check this : http://www.pocketmagic.net/2011/03/android-contacts-invoke-the-edit-contact-intent/#.UNLZMVLBbcs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on Button click do the following:

```
        Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
        in.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        startActivityForResult(in,EDIT_CONTACT);
```

and in onActivityResult Function do this:

case EDIT_CONTACT:

```
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor cur = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                ContentResolver contect_resolver = getContentResolver();

                if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name = "";
                    String no = "";
                    String key = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));


                    String where = ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " = ? AND " + 
                    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND " +
                    String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE) + " = ? ";
                    String[] params = new String[] {name,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                    String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME)};

                    Cursor phoneCur = contect_resolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

                    if (phoneCur.moveToFirst()) {
                        name = phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        no = phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        key = phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));

                        System.out.println("EDITIDDDDDDDDDD"+name);
                        System.out.println("EDITIDDDDDDDDDD"+no);
                        System.out.println("EDITIDDDDDDDDDD"+key);



                    /*ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

                    if ( (null == phoneCur)  ) {
        //                          createContact(name, phone);
                      } else {
                        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                                .withSelection(where, params)
                                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA, no)
                                .build());
                    }

                    phoneCur.close();

                    try {
                        cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
             */



                    id = null;
                    name = null;
                    no = null;
                    phoneCur = null;
                    key = null;

                contect_resolver = null;
                cur = null;

                             }
                    }
            }

        break;
```

Comment: ok try, i have not checked about this... so let me know if it works

Comment: How to get last inserted contact id.Please let me know

Comment: getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);   
select = "(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " == \"" +first_name+" "+last_name +"\" )"; Cursor c1 =  getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
      startManagingCursor(c1);
      int id=0;
      if (c1.moveToNext())
      {  
       id = new Integer(c1.getString(0)).intValue(); 
       System.out.println("Nativecontacid of this new addedcontact"+id);
       
      }

Comment: see above code i have used to fetch last inserted contact id using tha contact firstname and lastname. But i have doubt if that name is already present in db problem may b occur. so how to get last inserted contact id after inserting the contact

Comment: to know about last inserted contactid, i would say you to use LOOKUP_KEY in contacts

Comment: key = phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));

Comment: In the key itself,will i get the contact id..?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21456/discussion-between-g-m-ramesh-and-androidraji)