# Deleting duplicate contacts from custom contact list

Tags: java, android, arraylist, duplicates, contacts

I have created a custom contact list but some of the contacts get duplicated. I have read other question in SO but didn't got any solution.
How can I remove these duplicates?

Here is how the list gets populated:

```
protected Void doInBackground(String[] filters) {
        String filter = filters[0];
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = new String[]{
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
        };
        Cursor cursor;
        if(filter.length()>0) {
            cursor = contentResolver.query(
                    uri,
                    projection,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ?",
                    new String[]{filter},
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC"
            );
        }else {
            cursor = contentResolver.query(
                    uri,
                    projection,
                    null,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC"
            );
        }
        totalContactsCount = cursor.getCount();
        if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0){
            while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

                    String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
                            new String[]{id},
                            null
                    );

                    if (phoneCursor != null && phoneCursor.getCount() > 0) {
                        while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                            String phId = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID));

                            String customLabel = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL));

                            String label = (String) ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone
                                    .getTypeLabel(context.getResources(),
                                    phoneCursor.getInt(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE)),
                                    customLabel
                            );
                            String phNo = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                            tempContactHolder.add(new Contact(phId, name, phNo, label));
                        }
                        phoneCursor.close();
                    }
                }
                loadedContactsCount++;
                publishProgress();
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Here is the Contact class

```
public class Contact implements Parcelable {

    public String id,name,phone,label;

    Contact(String id, String name,String phone,String label){
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.phone=phone;
        this.label=label;
    }

    protected Contact(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readString();
        name = in.readString();
        phone = in.readString();
        label = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Contact> CREATOR = new Creator<Contact>() {
        @Override
        public Contact createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Contact(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Contact[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Contact[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return name+" | "+label+" : "+phone;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(id);
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(phone);
        dest.writeString(label);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `tempContactHolder` defined?

Comment: It is defined outside the doInBackground

Comment: check for duplicate contacts and delete with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710028/how-to-delete-a-particular-contact-using-contact-id)

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial solution, more of a workaround.  You could work with a set of contacts instead of a list, i.e. use:

```
Set<Contact> tempContactHolder;
```

Then, when adding a duplicate contact it would effectively be ignored.

If you must use a list to store contacts, because your code requires a list at some point, then to remove duplicates you can add the list to a set, which will remove duplicates.  Then, add the set contents back to your list, i.e.

```
Set<Contact> set = new HashSet<>();
set.addAll(tempContactHolder);
tempContactHolder.clear();
tempContactHolder.addAll(set);
```

The best answer might be to figure out what in your logic is causing duplicates to be added, and stop that from happening.

**Update:**

If the above logic be not working, one possible explanation is that you never defined an `equals()` method for your `Contact` class.  Java uses the `equals()` method when determining duplicates with regard to addition to a set, so this is critical for the above code snippet to work.  You can try adding the following `equals()` method to your `Contact` class:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Contact.class.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass())) {
        return false;
    }
    final Contact other = (Contact) obj;
    if ((this.id == null) ? (other.id != null) : !this.id.equals(other.id)) {
        return false;
    }
    if ((this.name == null) ? (other.name != null) : !this.name.equals(other.name)) {
        return false;
    }
    if ((this.phone == null) ? (other.phone != null) : !this.phone.equals(other.phone)) {
        return false;
    }
    if ((this.label == null) ? (other.label != null) : !this.label.equals(other.label)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Is there any other way to create a custom contact list with checkboxes?

Comment: `This doesn't work` ... what about my solution doesn't work?

Comment: Update your question and show us the `Contact` class.  Perhaps your `equals()` logic is resulting in unexpected behavior.